# Check the list contains all the specified items

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of company type ids containing values 1 to 30
In every transaction I have some companies involved in that transaction.

I want to check if all the companies in that particular transaction have ids as 6,16

I am using like this way 
    list.All(x => x.id == 6 || x.id == 16)

But this will work only if that transaction contains all the companies as id 6 or 16.But this condition will fail if one company have id 6 and other will have 16.

Any help?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a [mcve]

Comment: What to edit in this thing because I am just stuck on the above linq?

Comment: Add the relevant code you are using. You are not likely using one single line

Comment: Ok sorry will remember the next time

Comment: "I want to check if all the companies in that particular transaction have ids as 6,16" - can you clarify what this means? Your code sample suggests that they can only have a single ID so what does "all companies have ids as 6 or 16 mean? I assume it means that all companies have one or the other id but this is exactly what your code is doing. You say "this condition will fail if one company have id 6 and other will have 16" but your code will only fail if it finds a company whose id is neither 6 not 16 (ie if the ids are 6,6,6,16,6,16,6 then it will pass).

Answer (score 0):

Try to find items that does not belong to any of the ids.

```
var fail = list.Any(item => item.id != 6 && item.id != 16);
```

**UPDATE for issue with sub-type id**

```
var fail = list.Any(item => item.id != 6 && !(item.id == 16 && item.subtypeid == 100));
```

Maybe easier to read the logic if we do some boolean algebra tricks and change the AND logic to OR-logic;

```
var fail = list.Any(item => !(item.id == 6 || (item.id == 16 && item.subtypeid == 100)));
```

Comment: `.Count() > 0` == `.Any()`. Also, `.Where(condition).Count()` == `.Count(condition)`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Good point :-) Never really used Any(). Will start to do so

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto And so `.Where(condition).Count() > 0` == `.Any(condition)`:)

Comment: @Frode: I have one more case so previously i was checking that all the companies should only be 6 and 16.So u suggested that find items which does not belong to 6 and 16.But for 16 now I have also to check the subtypeid.Actually for 16 I have 2 subtypeids 100 and 110.I only have to check with subtypeid 100.So now the updated logic will be to check the companies having ids 6 and 16 but for 16 only with subtypeid 100.So 6 will be alone checked and 16 will be alongwith subtypeid 100 checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool result = new HashSet<int>{ 6, 16 }.SetEquals(list.Select(x => x.id));
```

> [The SetEquals method ignores duplicate entries and the order of elements in the other parameter.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346516(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks)

Comment: I completed the implementation.....but great to learn about HashSet.Thank u